# Largest Number Drawn - RV

Tags: probability, random-variables

From a box containing N identical tickets numbered 1 to N, n tickets are drawn with replacement. Let X be the largest number drawn. Find E[X]. Rohatgi 3.2 (2nd problem)

My solution 2:

I thought about using the Indicator RV.

X<sub>i</sub> = 1, if the i<sup>th</sup> draw is the largest

X<sub>i</sub> = 0, o/w

Now, E[X<sub>i</sub>] = Pr {X<sub>i</sub> = 1}
                      = 1/i {Since each of other i-1 numbers could be the largest}

=> E[X] = $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^N 1/i$

Does it make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: That says you're calculating an infinite sum which should tip you off that something isn't right. Why don't you start by calculating the pmf of $X = \max{ \{ X_1, ... , X_n \} }$?

Comment: @Tyler Yeah, sorry the summation should be from 1 to N. But still the probability part is confusing for me.

Comment: @user2761431: Yes.

Comment: That formula allows the possibility that 2 is the largest number, but the smallest value of the largest number is $n$.

Comment: I've got to leave this moment but if this still isn't answered a bit later I'll write something up. I encourage you to try following my above hint though. Another hint: We should expect that E(X) -> N as we draw more tickets, right?

Comment: Whoops, it says with replacement, I solved without replacement.

Comment: Your 2nd solution doesn't make sense either. The expected value should depend on the number of times you draw.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ be the value of the $i^{th}$ ticket drawn. Let $X$ denote the largest value drawn, and notice that $X = \max{ \{ X_1, ..., X_n \}}$. Let's try to find the pmf of $X$. This is actually easiest if we use CDFs.

$F_X(k)=P(X \leq k)=P(\max{ \{ X_1, ..., X_n \}} \leq k) = P((X_1 \leq k) \cap ... \cap (X_n \leq k))$.

The second equality holds because we need *each* of the $X_i$ to be less or equal to $k$ if we want the maximum to be less or equal to $k$.

Now notice that we are sampling the tickets with replacement, so each draw is independent. This allows us to say

$P((X_1 \leq k) \cap ... \cap (X_n \leq k)) = P(X_1 \leq k)\cdot \cdot \cdot P(X_n \leq k) = P(X_i \leq k)^n$.

Again, since we are sampling with replacement, he last equality holds because each draw has the same distribution. Now we know that each $X_i$ is a discrete uniform distribution on the set $ \{ 1, 2, ... N \}$, so, putting it all together, what we end up with is

$F_X(k) = P(X_i = k)^n = (k/N)^n$.

From this we can easily find $p_X(k)$, and then $E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^{N} kp_X(k)$

Answer (score 1):

Pick your $n$ numbers.  There are ${N^n}$ ways to do that.
The number of ways the maximum is $k$ is ${k^n-(k-1)^n}$.
The sum you want is $\sum_{k=1}^N k \Pr(\max=k)\\=
\sum_{k=1}^N [k^{n+1}-k(k-1)^n]/N^n\\=N-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(k/N)^n$

Comment: pretty sleek :)

Comment: @Michael How did you arrive at the last step? I am not getting the last step.

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^N [k^{n+1}-k(k-1)^n]/N^n\\=\sum_{k=1}^N [k^{n+1}-(k-1+1)(k-1)^n]/N^n\\=\sum_{k=1}^N [k^{n+1}-(k-1)^{n+1}-(k-1)^{n+1}]/N^n\\=\sum_{k=1}^N [N-(k-1)^{n+1}]/N^n\\=N-\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}(k-1/N)^n$

Comment: $k-1$ instead of $k$ in Micheal answer.

Comment: I think the highest that is subtracted should be $((N-1)/N)^n, and the lowest should be $0$ or $1/N$, doesn't matter which.

Comment: Right extreme $k-1$ power in second and third last step is $n$, unfortunately I cant edit it.